# Shortcut to get PhpStorm to wrap or unwrap the current line with /* */ comment tags

Tags: comments, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

Not sure whether there would be an existing shortcut for this or not, but if so, what is it, and if not, how can I create one?

I want it to essentially toggle the wrapping of slash-star comment tags, so if the line is commented already, it becomes uncommented. Eg from:

```
/*padding-left: 10px;*/
```

to

```
padding-left: 10px;
```

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/PhpStorm_ReferenceCard.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 standard actions for working with comments:

- `Comment with Line Comment` <kbd>Ctrl + /</kbd>
- `Comment with Block Comment` <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + /</kbd>

CSS does not have single line comments, only block comments, but `Comment with Line Comment` works just fine: it comments and uncomments current line (or selected lines) by applying or removing comment for each line individually.

Block comment works with selections only and applies single comment to whole selection.

**P.S.**
Those shortcuts are for Windows using Default keymap. For other OS / keymaps check it in `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Appearance & Behaviour | Keymap` (that's for PhpStpm v8.0.2, for 8.0.1 and older the settings path is slightly different)

Comment: I'd add that tapping `Ctrl`+`W` a couple of times will usually select the whole line. I don't see a shortcut for 'select current line'.

Comment: @ClementMandragora Search for `Select Line at Caret` in `Settings | Keymap` -- it does not have shortcut in Default keymap. Plus, you do not need to make selection for `single line comment` action -- it works with current line by default.